# Updating variable every x minutes

Tags: c, ipc, glib

I have a small program, which uses glib.
You can see it in codereview. The title is "Reading messages. What can be done better?".
I have a endless while loop in a main method.
In this loop I have a GTree.

```
int main()
{
  //some setup/mallocs
  GTree* t = g_tree_new_full((GCompareDataFunc)g_ascii_strcasecmp,NULL,free_data,free_data);
  while (1) {
     //some tasks; accessing tree   
  } 
  //some free
}
```

Tree is accessed inside this loop.
I wish to update this  tree every x minutes(for example every 15 minutes).
Is it possible? How can I do it and avoid collisions?

Comment: Create two threads. Write the updating tree part in a function. Call the function from one thread and sleep for 15 mins. The other thread can do the routine jobs.

Comment: This would work but keep in mind that, like most data structures in glib, GTree is *not* thread-safe, so if you want to access it from multiple threads simultaneously you need to use an external synchronization primitive (i.e., a mutex).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing while (1) { ... } in your code, use [GLib's main event loop](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html).  Beyond making this a lot easier, it will also allow you to integrate with other main loop based code, such as GTK+, the asynchronous functions in GIO and other libraries.

```
gboolean every_15_minutes (gpointer user_data) {
  /* some tasks; accessing tree */
}

int main (void) {
  GMainLoop* loop = g_main_loop_new (NULL, FALSE);
  /* some setup/mallocs */
  GTree* t = g_tree_new_full((GCompareDataFunc)g_ascii_strcasecmp,NULL,free_data,free_data);
  g_timeout_add_seconds (60 * 15, every_15_minutes, NULL);
  g_main_loop_run (loop);
  /* some free */
}
```

As for avoiding collisions, you could do a [g_tree_lookup](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Balanced-Binary-Trees.html#g-tree-lookup) to verify there aren't any existing entries with that key before a [g_tree_insert](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Balanced-Binary-Trees.html#g-tree-lookup), or just do a [g_tree_replace](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Balanced-Binary-Trees.html#g-tree-lookup) which will discard the old value if there is a collision.

Comment: with collisions i meant, that I don't want to insert/update tree ( in every_15_minutes function) when it is accessed in the while (1) {} loop. Maybe you didn't get me correct. I wish to have a loop which access the tree and in addition I want to modify this tree every 15 minutes.

Comment: You can add more than one callback to a main loop.  They don't even have to be based on a timeout—they can be based on I/O availability, or even just executed whenever the loop is idle.

Comment: I see. And is it save? Don't I need any block for callbacks?

Comment: The main loop doesn't create threads, so unless you create threads elsewhere you don't need to worry about thread safety.